# Redirect after login saving my post vars

Tags: zend-framework, redirect

I have 2 Applications. 
MyApp and a MainApp.
MyApp gets "controlled" by MainApp.
MyApp is made with Zend.

MainApp makes different requests to MyApp. E.g. MyApp/index/create, /copy, /delete etc.
MainApp needs to be logged in at MyApp to be able to do this requests.

If MainApp (or actually he user which is using MainApp) isn't logged in at MyApp, he will get logged in automatically in the background without noticing it. Because of this, each request from MainApp to MyApp will include the credentials as post variables.

So, a little example:

MainApp isn't logged in at MyApp:

Request:
1. MainApp -> MyApp/index/create
2. MyApp Plugin: Is he logged in? ... No, redirect to MyApp/index/login
3. MyApp/login/index, login was sucessfully, redirect to MyApp/index/create

This is basically not that complicated. There are 2 problems to care about: Knowing the origin location from the last request and the post vars.

Problem 1 - Last Request: Could be written into Zend Registry or passed as GET parameters at redirection.
Problem 2 - Passing the credentials to login action: Can i add them as get parameters too? Can i somehow make a post redirect? Maybe i can save the request obj and pass it to the login action, to recall it? Maybe i should write the post stuff into registry too?

Atm ,the login is unsecure, didn't add that yet. Is there anything i need to care when making it secure?

Thanks
$_redirect();

Comment: You seem to want to use `Zend_Registry` as storage between requests. It does not work this way, it only stores data during lifetime of a single request in your ZF app.

Comment: Also, how do MainApp and MyApp communicate? Using AJAX (client (user) -> server(MyApp)) or `curl` (server (MainApp) -> server (MyApp)) or ..?

Comment: Atm, i just did create a plugin which checks if the user is logged in, if not the plugin logs him in. But i don't know, if this is a bad idea. Both apps are on the same server. I've never used curl and never had to do a communication between 2 applications on the same server. For some little testing, i just used ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The original problem is still unclear to me in details, so I'll relate to your problems 1 and 2 explicitly.

Problem 1.

Last request can be saved using SESSION, with ZF you can do it easily for example like this:

```
$ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace("main_app_data_for_my_app");
$ns->lastRequest = $request->getServer("REQUEST_URI");
//now redirect to login
//after login create `$ns` and read the `lastRequest` property
//(and preferably unset it afterwards)
```

Problem 2.

You can't do a regular redirect with POST data, so I'd say - take a look at the solution to problem 1, namely SESSION. Of course this means you will have to make the login action aware of the SESSION variables' existence, but because I don't know the implementation details I can't tell if it's good or bad.

Comment: Thanks. But actually i just can create a plugin on preDispatch, check for the login and also do the login there. Think this works well. BUt thanks a lot, I'll take a look at it.